# Show 3 result from each element in group by

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am working on a system for handling meter reading.

I want to produce a output where the system displays all the meters belonging to the customer and for each meter, the three last readings.

So far, I have to followering code:

```
 var lastMeterReading = from meeters in metermodel.Meeters
                              join reading in metermodel.Readings on meeters.MeterNumber equals reading.MeterNumber
                              where (maalers.CustNo == 6085574)
                              orderby reading.Date descending
                              group meeters by new { meeters.MeterNumber, reading.Consumption, reading.Date } into result
                              select new
                              {
                                  Consumption = result.Key.Consumption, No = result.Key.MeterNumber, Date = result.Key.Date
                              };
```

Now, it shows all the meters belonging to the customer. If I put a .take(3), it only shows the first 3 results.

Thx!
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is to put the .Take(3) in the right place.
In you case you probably did result.Take(3) but this means take the first three groups (with all their elements).

Below is an attempt to show what I mean, however, I suppose you will need to fix it in the last part, as I don't have data to test it on, and as such I'm not sure if what I'm trying to access is accessible at that point. But I hope you get what I mean.

```
var lastMeterReading = (from meeters in metermodel.Meeters
                       join reading in metermodel.Readings on meeters.MeterNumber equals reading.MeterNumber
                       where (maalers.CustNo == 6085574)
                       orderby reading.Date descending
                       group meeters by new { meeters.MeterNumber, reading.Consumption, reading.Date } into result
                       from m in result
                       select new {Key = m.Key, Info = result.OrderByDescending(r => r.Date).Take(3)})
                       .Select(r => new 
{ Consumption = r.Consumption, No = r.MeterNumber, Date = r.Date });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var lastMeterReading = from meeters in metermodel.Meeters
                       join reading in metermodel.Readings on meeters.MeterNumber equals reading.MeterNumber
                       where (maalers.CustNo == 6085574)
                       orderby reading.Date descending
                       group meeters by new { meeters.MeterNumber, reading.Consumption, reading.Date } into result
                       from m in result.Take(3)
                       select new
                       {
                           Consumption = m.Consumption, No = m.MeterNumber, Date = m.Date
                       };
```

Comment: Hmm, it says that meters.Take(3) does not exist in the current context.
I have spelled meters wrong, but it still says it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You only want to group by *MeterNumber*. The way you're doing the grouping right now, you'll get a new group for every unique *MeterNumber-Consumption-Date* combination.

You can also simplify your query using LINQ's GroupJoin operator. In query syntax you use the "join..on..into" pattern:

```
from meter in meterModel.Meters
  where (meter.CustNo == 6085574)
  join reading in meterModel.Readings
  on meter.MeterNumber equals reading.MeterNumber
  into meterGroup
  select meterGroup.OrderByDescending(r => r.Date).Take(3);
```

Or using dot notation:

```
meterModel.Meters
    .Where(x => x.CustNo == 6085574)
    .GroupJoin(
        meterModel.Readings, 
        meter => meter.MeterNumber, 
        reading => reading.MeterNumber, 
        (meter,readings) => readings.OrderByDescending(r => r.Date).Take(3))
    ;
```